# Continuity of the restriction of a function to a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f$ a real-valued function defined on $X$. Let $S\subset X$ and suppose $f$ is continuous with respect to the induced topology on $S$ (opens are in the form $S\cap V$, where $V$ is an open of $X$). Is this the same as saying that the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the same, the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is continuous if it is continuous with the induced topology by definition

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly the definition. However we cannot conclude that $f$ is a continuous at points of $S$ when considered as a function on $X$. Example: $S$ is the set of rationals and $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational, $0$ for $x$ irrational